# Selecting a List Inside a List in Python

Tags: python

```
stats=[[5,1,4],[3,4,3],[2,3,5]]
```

I was just wondering how I would select an element and I can't find anything that will help. for example, how would I select the 2 in the last set of numbers

Comment: `stats[-1][0]`?

Answer (score 1):

its called 2 dimensional list and below is the way. thanks

`stats[2][0]`